# Verifying data types/structs in a parser

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, scope, compiler-theory

I'm writing a recursive descent parser, and I'm at the point where I'm unsure how to validate everything. I'm not even sure if I should be doing this at the stage of the parser. What I mean is, I could have some syntax i.e:

```
int x = 5
int x = 5
```

And that would be valid, so would the parser check if x has already been defined? If so, would I use a hashmap? And what kind of information would I need to store, like how can I handle the scope of a variable, since x could be defined in a function in a local and global scope:

```
int x = 5;
void main() {
    int x = 2;
}
```

And finally, when I store to the hashmap, how can I differentiate the types? For example, I could have a variable called `foo`, and a struct also called `foo`. So when I put `foo` in a hashmap, it will probably cause some errors. I'm thinking I could prefix it like storing this as the hashmaps key for a struct `struct_xyz` where xyz is the name of the struct, and for variables `int_xyz`?
Thanks :)

Comment: That's not parser's job. The parser builds a syntax tree. Other stages verify the semantics is valid.

Comment: It sounds like you need a review of the first term study of [The Dragon Book.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). Lexers build tokens from input, Parsers validate syntax of token streams against the language grammar. *Neither* are destined for the task you're describing

Comment: @n.m. Cool, so the parser just builds it even if the stuff on there is wrong?

Comment: @WhozCraig So what part of an interpreter/compiler would do this?

Comment: Am I thinking of Semantic Analysis?

Comment: The lexer chunks a string without knowing whether the sequence of tokens makes sense. The parser builds a tree without knowing if the sequence of statements it encodes makes sense. It's _semantic analysis_ that looks at the parse tree and sees undeclared or redeclared variables and says "this is wrong".

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Great, thanks! This is nice to know since it means I won't have to worry about implementing it just yet :) Should I delete this question, or perhaps someone could put an answer in or something?

Comment: @user3839220 Sry, just saw your comment, yes, that's the most common place.

Comment: Can the parser do some error checking? Like if theres an unexpected token can it say?

Comment: @user3839220 It must; I'm gonna sound like a broken record, but each component handles different classes of errors. A lexer errors on foreign objects (like a `\`` backtick, which isn't a valid character anywhere in a C program), a parser errors on syntax (like a missing `;` where one was expected), and a semantic analyzer errors on nonsensical code (syntactically well-formed code that is still incorrect, like redeclarations `int x;int x;`. They are both syntactically valid (`nameofType nameofVar;`), it's their togetherness that is bad).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Actually, a back-tick can appear in a character constant or a character string, but your general point is clear and well stated.

Comment: Books like the Dragon Book try to convey an idealized picture of the structure of a compiler. In doing so, I think they tend to overemphasize the importance of keeping the stages' responsibilities separated. For example, it's sometimes useful for the parser and lexer to interact more like coroutines than separate pipeline stages. Sorry. I don't think there's anything inherently *wrong* with the parser taking on some of the responsibilities traditionally delegated to the "semantic analyzer" (whatever that even means!).

Comment: @MartinTörnwall: Point well taken, but it is often tempting to put a shortcut into your pipeline only to find later that it has unfortunate consequences. For example, binding names to scopes while parsing is tempting, but it precludes language constructs where names are used before their definition. Classic case in point: list comprehensions. Python `[x+3 for x in values]` or Haskell `[ transform x | x <- values ]`. (Haskell `where` expressions are another example, and there are many others.)

Comment: Indeed it does! I'm naturally not proposing that one ought to design a language that prohibits use-before-definition just to allow the parser to build the symbol table. :-) But if the language you are implementing already suffers from this deficiency, I figure you may as well exploit it. The point I'm really trying to make is that you don't necessarily have to follow the textbook's model to the letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that regardless of which approach you choose, your parser will be constructing some kind of abstract syntax tree. You now have two options. Either, the parser could populate the tree with identifier nodes that store the name of the variable or function that they are referencing. This leaves the issue of scope resolution to a later pass, as advocated in many compiler textbooks.

The other option is to have the parser immediately look the identifier up in a symbol table that it builds as it goes, and store a pointer to the symbol in the abstract syntax tree node instead. This approach tends to work well if your language doesn't allow implicit forward-references to names that haven't been declared yet.

I recently implemented the latter approach in a compiler that I'm working on, and I've been very pleased with the result so far. I will briefly describe my solution below.

Symbols are stored in a structure that looks something like this:

```
typedef struct symbol {
    char  *name;
    Type  *type;
    Scope *scope; // Points to the scope in which the symbol was defined.
} Symbol;
```

So what is this `Scope` thing? The language I'm compiling is lexically scoped, and each function definition, block, etc, introduces a new scope. Scopes form a stack where the bottom element is the global scope. Here's the structure:

```
typedef struct scope {
    struct scope *parent;
    Symbol *buckets;
    size_t  nbuckets;
} Scope;
```

The `buckets` and `nbuckets` fields are a hash map of identifiers (strings) to `Symbol` pointers. By following the `parent` pointers, one can walk the scope stack while searching for an identifier.

With the data structures in place, it's easy to write a parser that resolves names in accordance with the rules of lexical scoping.

1. Upon encountering a statement or declaration that introduces a new scope (such as a function declaration or a block statement), the parser pushes a new `Scope` onto the stack. The new scope's `parent` field points to the old scope.
2. When the parser sees an identifier, it tries to look it up in the current scope. If the lookup fails in the current scope, it continues recursively in the `parent` scope, etc. If no corresponding `Symbol` can be found, an error is raised. If the lookup is successful, the parser creates an AST node with a pointer to the symbol.
3. Finally, when a variable or function declaration is encountered, it is bound in the current scope.

Some languages use more than one namespace. For instance, in Erlang, functions and variables occupy different namespaces, requiring awkward syntax like `fun foo:bar/1` to get at the value of a function. This is easily implemented in the model I outlined above by keeping several `Scope` stacks - one for each namespace.

Comment: Minor note: search time in this data structure is linear on scope nesting level.

Comment: Awesome, loads of detail this helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If we define "scope" or "context" as mapping from variable names to types (and possibly some more information, such as scope depth), then its natural implementation is either hashmap or some sort of search tree. Upon reaching any variable definition, compiler should insert the name with corresponding type into this data structure. When some sort of 'end scope' operator is encountered, we must already have enough information to 'backtrack' changes in this mapping to its previous state.

For hashmap implementation, for each variable definition we can store previous mapping for this name, and restore this mapping when we have reached the 'end of scope' operator. We should keep a stack of stacks of this changes (one stack for each currently open scope), and backtrack topmost stack of changes in the end of each scope.

One drawback of this approach is that we must either complete compilation in one pass, or store mapping for each identifier in program somewhere, as we can't inspect any scope more than once, or in order other than order of appearance in the source file (or AST).

For tree-based implemetation, this can be easily achieved with so called [persistent trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Trees). We just maintain a stack of trees, one for each scope, pushing as we 'open' some scope, and poping when the scope is ended.

The 'depth of scope' is enough for choose what to do in the situation where then new variable name conflicts with one already in mapping. Just check for `old depth < new depth` and overwrite on success, or report error on failure.

To differentiate between function and variable names you can use separate (yet similar or same) mappings for those objects. If some context permits only function or only variable name, you already know where to look. If both are permited in some context, perform lookup in both structures, and report "ambiguity error" if name corresponds to a function and a variable at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use a class, where you define structures like HashMap, that lets you to do controls about the type and or the existence of a variable. This class should have static methods that interface with the grammar rules written in the parser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Note that this question is tagged 'C' and not 'C++', which makes a 'class' a bit problematic.  I'm not clear why the class should have static methods; why not regular member functions?  However, that's somewhat tangential to the question.

Comment: First of all I apologize for my answer. I didn't understood the language used for the creation of the compiler and I supposed it was Java. And so, I suggested the use of static methods, because I've seen on cup that this kind of method is requested, when you call it in the customization of the grammar rule, beetween {: and :}